# Add existing objects to Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I couldn't find anything about this topic. I have NSManagedObjects that I don't use insertNewObject... I use alloc init, and then add them to array sort them alphabetically, and then I want to add them to entities and save the context. Any ideas on how to add them to entities, without making entirely new objects?

Comment: why not just insert them rather than alloc'ing them - i.e. what is the reason for taking this approach?  Sorting can be done on retrieval and insert order doesn't determine retrieval order.

Comment: @Devfly Whyyyyyy? Apple expressly forbids doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be more proper as a comment, but it is, in fact, the answer.

Do not do that.  First, read the documentation, then use the API as directed.

Directly from the documentation for `NSManagedObject`:

> It is important that a managed object is properly configured for use
>   with Core Data. If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must
>   call the designated initializer
>   (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:).

Then, from the documentation for `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`

> Important  This method is the designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.

Note, that the above statement is actually highlighted in an attention-getting box in the documentation.